# RefreshView when target Platform is UWP then it is not wokring

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

RefreshView when target paltform is UWP it is not working i.e I'am unable to apply pull to refresh, but on iOS and Android it is Working fine.

Comment: Hi @Varunvir Jaiswal any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

> RefreshView when target paltform is UWP it is not working

I have to say the RefreshView only avaiable for touch screen, if you use mouse mode, it will not response your drag gestue. please run your app with simulator or touch device.

For more detail please refer to [Run UWP apps in the simulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-in-the-simulator?view=vs-2019) document